# How many connections and streams are opened by NGINX to backends when loadbalancing with ngx_http_grpc_module

Tags: nginx, grpc

I'm using [ngx_http_grpc_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_grpc_module.html) to balance RPCs across a number of backends. Sadly I have little control over the backends and it's hard for me to inspect the exact behavior.

In my mind there are two types of concurrency in use:

- the number of connections opened to each backend
- the number of streams per connection

If I open up one connection to an nginx instance, it opens at least one connection to each backend to balance the RPCs across them.

What I'm not sure about is:

- when I open more connections up to nginx (e.g. more clients) are additional connections opened to backends too?
- how does nginx determine the number of streams that are used in each connection to each backend?

Answer (score 2):

NGINX (Open Source and Plus) opens per request exactly one connection to exactly one server from the upstream. Which server is actually selected depends on the load balance directive. You can direct multiple requests to the same upstream server via *ip_hash* or *hash* directive. Server is selected round-robin if no directive given or via some other directives, e.g. by number of active connections via *least_conn*. NGINX Plus offers more capabilities via sticky connections.

See: [Docs for Module ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

To understand load balancing, connections and channels read these free eBooks from NGINX:

[The Complete NGINX Cookbook](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/complete-nginx-cookbook/)

[Deploying NGINX Plus as an API Gateway](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/nginx-api-gateway-deployment/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I have two follow-up questions, do you have the link to the relevant part of the docs? Also, anywhere in the docs about how the requests/rpcs are balanced over connections open to backends - crucially, does a backend with more connections get more requests/rpcs?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, I wasn't able to find any specific details answering my questions above in the linked books - they seem quite high level.